# Probing the target board failed - DJI Manifold G

Tags: linux

I am trying to flash the DJI Manifold 2G with the official DJI image. When I try to flash it using the command,

```
sudo ./flash.sh jetson-tx2 mmcblk0p1
```

the error appears:

```
###############################################################################
# L4T BSP Information:
# R28 (release), REVISION: 2.1, GCID: 11272647, BOARD: t186ref, EABI: aarch64, 
# DATE: Thu May 17 07:29:06 UTC 2018
###############################################################################
Error: probing the target board failed.
       Make sure the target board is connected through 
       micro-B USB port and is in recovery mode.
```

I have checked using "lsusb" command to make the sure the board is in recovery mode and it is as shown here"

```
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0b05:6208 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. C-Media(R) Audio
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 021: ID 0955:7c18 NVIDIA Corp. T186 [TX2 Tegra Parker] recovery mode
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56a2 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am also using a micro-USB B cable, and I have tried by attaching, detaching cable and even rebooting the system, it does not work. Could anyone help me out here please?

Answer (score 0):

**Check the USB Cable:**
Make sure you are using a high-quality USB cable. Sometimes, using a different cable can resolve connection issues. Try a different micro-USB B cable and ensure that it supports data transfer.

**Check Permissions:**
Ensure that you have the necessary permissions to access the USB device. You can try running the flash.sh script with sudo:
**sudo ./flash.sh jetson-tx2 mmcblk0p1**

**Reconnect USB Cable:**
Disconnect and reconnect the USB cable. Wait a few seconds after reconnecting to allow the system to detect the device properly.

**Try Different USB Port:**
Connect the Manifold 2G to a different USB port on your computer. Avoid using USB hubs, and connect directly to a USB port on your computer if possible.

**Check System Logs:**
Look at the system logs to get more information about the issue. You can use the dmesg command to view kernel logs:
**dmesg | grep -i "usb|tty"**

**Update Flashing Tools:**
Make sure you are using the latest version of the flashing tools. Check for updates or download the latest version from the DJI or NVIDIA website.

**Check Recovery Mode:**
Ensure that the Manifold 2G is in recovery mode during the flashing process. You can confirm this by checking the output of the lsusb command, which you've already done.

**Power Cycle the Manifold 2G:**
Try power cycling the Manifold 2G by disconnecting the power supply, waiting a few seconds, and then reconnecting it.